# $a_1 = 2, a_{n+1} = a^2_n + a_n,$ calculate $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

The following problem:

> $a_1 = 2, a_{n+1} = a^2_n + a_n,$ calculate $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}}$ .

So use the equation we can get $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{1 + a_n}}$, but then ... I have no idea what to do next. Any help?

Comment: The greedy Egyptian representation of 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you really need is $$\frac{1}{a_n}-\frac{1}{a_{n+1}}=\frac{1+a_n}{a_n(1+a_n)}-\frac{1}{a_{n+1}}=\frac{1+a_n}{a_{n+1}}-\frac{1}{a_{n+1}}=\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}.$$ The sum of the telescoping series is $1/a_1=1/2$, because $a_n$ is monotonic and can't have a finite limit $a$ (then, you would have $a=a+a^2)$.

Answer (score 1):

It can be proved that

$$\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{a_{N+1}}$$

and

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=\infty$$

So, we have

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}=\frac{1}{2}$$